# Use double index in matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix

I want to run a simulation which involves rates between different states. Each state is label by a pair of indices $(m,n)$, so that a certain rate $R_{(m,n)\rightarrow(m',n')}$ requires four indices in total.

What I try to do is to convert these double indices into a single index $j$. This would allow me to use standard matrix multiplication methods to calculate e.g. the product of two matrices
$$A_{j_1,j_2} = (B  C)_{j_1,j_2}$$

I do see, how to calculate the 1D index, by defining
$$j(n,m) = \sum_{n'=0..n-1}M(n) + m$$
Here $M(n)$ is the number of different $m$'s I have for a given $n$. This is the crucial part, the number of different $m$'s is different for each $n$.

However, i do not see how to get $m$ and $n$ back, in case $j$ is given and for a generic $M(n)$.

Is this a standard problem in computer science?

My question is: what strategy can I use to do matrix multiplications when I have double indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't this work? You create a map from $(m,n)$, the key-pair, to $j$, the value. For this you could use `std::map`. The reverse map to go from $j$ to $(m,n)$ is just a vector of pairs. Then you can use $j$-like index to perform the matrix operations.

Am I simplifying your problem too much?

Comment: Thanks, this works! I tried to do an analytical formula to get (m,n) back for a given j. But you are right, I can simply numerically store the mapping, then I do not need the formula for the reverse function.